# upload directly to aws s3 using fineuploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using below code to upload files to S3 with JS. Don't know what's going on wrong here. Any help will be highly appreciated..

```
request: {
                    endpoint: "https://photoform.s3.amazonaws.com",
                    inputName: 'name',
                    forceMultipart: false,
                    paramsInBody : true,
                    filenameParam : 'test',
                    params: {},
                    accessKey: "AKIAIM5CBG3WFLLZBTAA"
                },
                signature: {

                    //always included
                    "expiration": "2014-02-04T14:32:31.373Z",

                    signature : "Bv7MiXh5LM4nQGcK0HVgu27DmQE=",
                    policy: "eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE0LTAyLTA0VDE0OjMyOjMxLjM3M1oiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjogWyB7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ICJwaG90b2Zvcm0iIH0gLHsgImFjbCI6ICJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCIgfSx7IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSI6ImpwZyJ9LHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiJodHRwczovL2NzMzAuc2FsZXNmb3JjZS5jb20vYXBleC9MaXN0U2xpZGVyVXBsb2FkUGljc1N1Y2Nlc3MifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRrZXkiLCAiIl0gXX0=",

                    "conditions":
                    [
                        //always included
                        {"acl": "public-read"},

                        //always included
                        {"bucket": "photoform"},

                        //not included in IE9 and older or Android 2.3.x and older
                        {"Content-Type": "jpg"},

                        //always included
                        {"key": "AKIAIM5CBG3WFLLZBTAA"},

                        //always included
                        {"x-amz-meta-qqfilename": "test.jpg"}, 
                    ]
                },
                cors: {
                    expected: true, //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
                    sendCredentials: false, //if you want cookies to be sent along with the request
                    allowXdr: true
                },
```

Comment: What's the problem? What does not work? What's the error message? Please be more specific.

Comment: It looks like you have have misunderstood the blog post that details Fine Uploader S3.  The signed and base-64 encoded policy document must be returned from your server in response to a signature request by Fine Uploader.  Have a look at the links in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the documentation on the docs site that explains how to use Fine Uploader S3.  The signature option is not where you create your policy document.  Instead of hard-coding the policy document and signature in the signature option, you must specify an endpoint where Fine Uploader will send the policy document it creates.  Your server is expected to sign it and return the signature.

Useful links:

- [Creating a server for Fine Uploader s3](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html)
- [Fine Uploader S3 signature option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#signature)

Comment: I hard coded signature and policy directly into request. I am getting this error: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message> . <ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue><ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName><RequestId>0FBA68D6F8197A19</RequestId><HostId>gibXnLY/vYeKiddoPWXmjWBw7BVXMW0l/XzIOovzllJhaohMdvkyR2RjkONBSuqn</HostId></Error> Is there any way to get it done without using any server?

Comment: Yes, there is.  See the [no server uploads](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/no-server-uploads.html) section in the documentation.